# Customizing LockedException of spring security to send new status code to angular.js

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security

I am using spring 4 + hibernate 4 + spring security (RESTFull Webservice API)  and angular at front. (Very new to this all).

My failure handler is as follows:

```
    @Component
    public class AuthFailure extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
       response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
   }
}
```

If my request fails I get 401 response which is as expected. Now I want to add AccountLocked and CredentialsExpiredException functionality. I am setting "false" appropriately when I return "User". Again I do get response with status as 401.

```
    return new User(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, AuthorityUtils.NO_AUTHORITIES);
```

As I always get 401 and I do not get any user object inside response(Or may be don't know how to get it),  at front end I am unable to find whether it's due to bad credentials or account locked or credentials expired as I want to redirect to another page. I also tried to catch exceptions and tried to forward different statuses but does not seems to hit this code. I always get 401.

```
    @ExceptionHandler(LockedException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public ModelAndView handleLockedException(Exception e) {
    logger.error("Exception occurred => " + e.getMessage());
    return new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), e.getMessage(), "Spring security exception").asModelAndView();
}
```

Please help me -  how shall I handle at angular end so that I can redirect to appropriate page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think solution was very simple, just did not pay attention to AuthFailure method parameters. Modified my AuthFailuar as follows:

```
    @Component
    public class AuthFailure extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (exception instanceof LockedException) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_PRECONDITION_FAILED);
    }else if {
     ....

    } else {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

   }
}
```

Now as I have given different status codes I can easily differentiate at the front. Hope for somebody this would be helpful.